# Semi-complicated dereferencing in PHP 5.5

Tags: php, php-5.5

The general idea is like so:

- I have a class `test`
- The class has a public static property `$commands`
- `test::$commands` is an array of `key => Callback` pairs
- I have a key saved in `$cmdkey`

All this considered, I should be able to write this:

```
self::$commands[$cmdkey]($argument);
```

However, doing so yields:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: $commands
>   PHP Fatal error: Function name must be a string

I solved the issue by doing this:

```
$callback = self::$commands[$cmdkey];
$callback($argument);
```

It's kind of a blowback to before dereferencing was a thing in PHP, though...

Am I going crazy, or have I actually found a bug in the PHP parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like

```
test::$commands[$cmdkey](foo)
```

is interpreted as

```
test::($commands[$cmdkey])(foo)
```

i.e. first fetch what `$commands[$cmdkey]` contains and use that as a function name in `test`. Note that just `test::$commands[$cmdkey]` binds normally.

Consider:

```
class test {
    public static $commands = array('x' => 'strlen');

    public static function other() {
        print 'here!';
    }
}

$cmdkey = 'x';

$commands = array('x' => 'other'); // *

print test::$commands[$cmdkey]('abc');
```

If you comment out the `*` line, you'll get

```
Notice: Undefined variable: commands...
Fatal error: Function name must be a string...
```

Sadly, http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php lacks `::` so it hard to say if this behaviour is intended, but it's definitely counter-intuitive.

This is what [PHPParser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) says:

```
$code = <<<'EOF'
<?php test::$commands[123](456); ?>
EOF;

$parser = new PhpParser\Parser(new PhpParser\Lexer);
$stmts = $parser->parse($code);
$nodeDumper = new PhpParser\NodeDumper;
print $nodeDumper->dump($stmts);
```

result:

```
0: Expr_StaticCall(
    class: Name(
        parts: array(
            0: test
        )
    )
    name: Expr_ArrayDimFetch(
        var: Expr_Variable(
            name: commands
        )
        dim: Scalar_LNumber(
            value: 123
        )
    )
    args: array(
        0: Arg(
            value: Scalar_LNumber(
                value: 456
            )
            byRef: false
            unpack: false
        )
    )
)
```